# Fixing Unknown Error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to make it so a new datatable gets created based on what rows the user selects in the datagridview, however I keep getting an error saying `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`
I have no clue what this means, and I was hoping I could get some help.

```
Private Function getCoordinates()

    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    'Dim r As DataRow
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim selectedItems As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = dgv.SelectedRows
    dt = dgv.DataSource
    dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgv.MultiSelect = True


    dt2.Columns.Add("Position")
    Try
        For Each selectedItem As DataGridView In selectedItems
            dt2.Rows.Add(n)
            dt2.Rows(n)("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
    End Try


    Return dt2
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: `For Each selectedItem As DataGridView In selectedItems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
For Each selectedItem As DataGridView In selectedItems
    dt2.Rows.Add(n)
    dt2.Rows(n)("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
Next
```

With

```
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems
    dt2.Rows.Add(selectedItem)
    ' dt2.Rows(n)("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
Next
```

Comment: When I step through it, when it adds the info it's actually not adding any info its just adding `DataGridViewRow {Index = x}`

Comment: Correct. That's the second step. You got you error vanished though. :)

Answer (score 2):

selectedItems contains a list of DataGridViewRow objects, not DataGridViews.  Update to the following:

```
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems
```